# Java -> Clojure -> Java

Tags: java, clojure

I am trying to use Clojure as a scripting language from a host Java program. The idea being that the end user will be able to write Clojure scripting code that will call a domain-specific Java API. At runtime, the host Java program will evaluate the end-user's Clojure script (which will in turn call the domain APIs). So I started with a dead-simple prototype to explore the terrain.

### domain

```
package a.problem.domain;

public class Domain {

    public Domain() { }

    public String defaultMsg() {
        return "default";
    }

    public String passBackMsg(String s) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

### Host Java program

(end user's Clojure script hard-coded for simplicity)

```
String script = "(do                                    "+
                "  (import '(a.problem.domain Domain))  "+
                "  (.defaultMsg (Domain.))              "+
                ")                                      ";
System.out.println(RT.var("clojure.core", "eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core","read-string").invoke(script)));
```

(code snippet taken from [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/12/clojure-java-interop.html))

So far so good.

However I couldn't find a way to invoke the second method (the one that requires an argument). Instead I resorted to dynamically generating the Clojure script at runtime and replacing a placeholder with a literal that represents the result of calling the domain method **passBackMsg**. Obviously, this is unsatisfactory and doesn't go very far (what if I want to pass a java.sql.Connection to my Clojure script ?).

So, how do I invoke the **passBackMsg** method from the host Java program?

When I try the following:

```
String script = "(ns foo)                                   "+ 
                "(import '(a.problem.domain Domain))        "+
                "(defn numberToString [s]  (                "+
                "  (.passBackMsg (Domain.) s)               "+
                "))                                         ";
RT.var("clojure.core", "eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core","read-string").invoke(script)); // line-A
System.out.println(RT.var("foo", "numberToString").invoke(33)); // line-B
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change/establish root binding of: *ns* with set
```

... on line-A. When I try without the ns and with:

```
RT.var("user", "numberToString").invoke(33)
```

("user" being a wild guess as I don't see a **var** method without a namespace argument)

I get an:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'user/numberToString"
```

... on line-B.

Comment: Couldn't you just `defn` a function through a `script` string and then `invoke` it just like you invoked `read-string`, by derefing its var?

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't get it to work. First it would accept defn and had to use (let (fn )) instead. Not a blocking problem but weird. Then I ran into some other problem. I didn't want to copy the failing code so as not to make the post too long, but after your message I might add it.

Comment: I have this working in a project of mine: `clojure.lang.RT.load(filename); clojure.lang.RT.var(mainNamespace, "main").invoke( stringArg );` Loading from a file shouldn't make a fundamental difference.

Comment: update on defn: it turns out that using a defn was not a problem after all and have updated the script shown, accordingly, the "Can't change/establish root binding of: *ns* with set" still persists however.

Comment: You definitely need a `do` around everything because `read-string` only reads one form. Also, `read-string` doesn't *evaluate* it, it just returns what was read in. This is in contrast to my technique with `load`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String script = "(do                                    "+
                "  (import '(a.problem.domain Domain))  "+
                "  (fn [s]                " +
                "   (.passBackMsg (Domain.) s)               "+
                "))                                         ";

IFn fn = (IFn)RT.var("clojure.core", "eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core","read-string").invoke(script));

fn.invoke("hello");
```

**UPDATED:**
Below sample code works fine:

```
package hello_clj;

import clojure.lang.RT;
import clojure.lang.IFn;

public class Main {

    public String passBackMsg(String s) {
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String script = "(do (import 'hello_clj.Main) (fn [s] " + 
                        "(.passBackMsg (Main.) s) ))";

        IFn fn = (IFn)RT.var("clojure.core", "eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core","read-string").invoke(script));
        System.out.print(fn.invoke("Hello"));
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be more reliable to do it without the `import` as it may not take effect within the same form as it is being evaluated. Did you try it?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn (thrown on line-A)

Comment: Updated the answer with a running sample code. The older code has extra params around fn and that was the issue.